# Conditional statements in Spring configuration

Tags: java, spring

Is it possible to use conditional statements in Spring config?

Depending on my Bundle's config file I'd like to inject a property - or not.

**Example:** 
In my Spring config I define a Bean that I'd like to inject later:

```
<spring:bean id="myClass" class="org.demo.MyClass"/>
```

Perfect would be something like if/end/else, etc.

```
<spring:bean id="someOtherClass" class="org.demo.SomeOtherClass">

    if ${my.config.doInject} == true then
        <spring:property name="injectedClass" ref="myClass" />
    end

    <spring:property name="someOtherProperty" value="12345"/>

</spring:bean>
```

So that later, in **SomeOtherClass**, I could check if **injectedClass** is Null - or not. And build some logic depending on that.

Comment: If you are using Spring 3+, Spring Java Config will let you make your configuration arbitrarily complex

Comment: Use jave based configuration then you can do all the java magic you want. If that isn't possible use a `FactoryBean` to construct your object. Don't program in XML.

Comment: You can use `-Dspring.active.profile=`

Comment: jeejava.com/conditional-statement-in-spring-config/

Answer (score 3):

You can use the SpEL ternary operator as described here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html

```
<spring:bean id="someOtherClass" class="org.demo.SomeOtherClass">
    <spring:property name="injectedClass" ref="#{ my.config.doInject ? myClass : null } />
    <spring:property name="someOtherProperty" value="12345"/>
</spring:bean>
```